# XML, XSL, how to fetch child nodes from xml file to xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an xml file that looks like this :

```
<TestRun>
 <FailedTests>
  <FailedTest id="19">
   <Name>Test</Name>
   <FailureType>Assertion</FailureType>
   <Location>
     <File>Sets.cpp</File>
   </Location>
   <Details>
     <Detail id="1">Exception caught returning cmd response </Detail>
     <Detail id="2">unresolvable error code</Detail>
   </Details>
  </FailedTest>
 </FailedTests>
</TestRun>
```

and i want to get the value of child nodes of TestRun/FailedTests/FailedTest/Details, how can i do this??
i tried this but it doesnt work :

```
        <TD>
            <xsl:for-each select="Details/Detail">
               <br></br><br></br>
            <xsl:value-of select="(Detail)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TD>
    </TR>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're inside the Details/Detail for-each you can print the content of the current element by doing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Comment: is there something wrong in my code??
or is there another way to extract child node values without giving their names??

Comment: your XSLT fragment isn't a valid XML plus I can't tell if your outermost for-each is called in the right context. maybe post a whole thing?